# Microsoft Access Creating an ACCDE file

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is my first post, I am trying to create a accde database file from my database, I keep getting an error message & decided to take a close look at my VBA code, I ran debug and I keep getting the error Compile error method or data member not found. My code is below any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks In Advance

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim UserLevel As Integer
    Dim TempPass As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter LoginID", vbInformation, "LoginID Required"
        Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
        Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
    Else
        'process the job
        If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'"))) Or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "Password='" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect LoginID or Password"
        Else
            UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
            TempPass = DLookup("password", "tblUser", "password = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'")
            ID = DLookup("UserID", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
            DoCmd.Close
            If (TempPass = "password") Then
                MsgBox "Please Change Your Password", vbInformation, "New Password Required"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "tblUser", , , "[UserID] = " & ID
            Else
                If UserLevel = 1 Then
                'MsgBox "Login Sucussfull"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Admin Navigation Form"
                Else
                    If UserLevel = 2 Then
                    'MsgBox "Login Sucussfull"
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "Area Director Navigation Form"
                        If UserLevel = 2 Then
                        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane -1
                        Else
                            DoCmd.OpenForm "Area Director Navigation Form"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line did the error occur on?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code and compile it (Debug --> Compile).

Comment: This part was highlighted.    .txtLoginID
& enderland I tried wat you said & replaced the Compare database with Explicit and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It might be the data type of txtLoginID. Is it a text or number field? If number, remove the single quote inside the DLookUps as shown below:

Previous:

`DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")`

Change:

`DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", "UserLogin = " & Me.txtLoginID.Value)`

Other side notes looking at your code:

1. Change your 'Command1' name of button control to a less generic name for better reference and code maintenance.
2. The .Value at end of control fields are redundant as it is the default text property.
3. Consider breaking up the first If Then logic that looks for missing ID and password and use 'Exit Sub' after outputting message boxes. Too many nested Ifs can be cumbersome to debug and follow all possible logic routes.